# I want to make a whitelisted command using quick.db

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, quick.db

I want to make a whitelist command using quickDB, so that if I do

!whitelist @user/userid

Then it stores data in the database

Comment: It's great, thanks for telling us what you want. However, StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You'll find your experience here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: This platform is to help you with your code/errors you're facing and not to spoon-feed you.

Now coming to your question

```js
const db = require('quick.db')
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!blacklist')) {

        let mentions = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (!mentions) {
            return message.reply({ content: `Please mention a user!` })
        } else {
            await db.push(`_blacklisted_`, mentions.id)//Including the mentioned member into the blacklisted list
            message.channel.send({ content: `Blacklisted **${mentions.tag}**` })
        }
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith('!whitelist')) {
        let mentions = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (!mentions) {
            return message.reply({ content: `Please mention a user!` })
        } else {
            let check_blacklist = await db.get(`_blacklisted_`, [])
            let index = check_blacklist.indexOf(mentions.id)
            if (index > -1) {
                check_blacklist.splice(index, 1)//remove the mentioned user from the blacklisted array
                await db.set(`_blacklisted_`, check_blacklist) //Setting the new list
                message.reply({ content: `Whitelisted ${mentions.tag}` })
            } else {
                message.reply({ content: `${mentions.username} is not blacklisted` })
            }

        }

    }
})
```

Do read the [docs](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs)